# Water damage to Garage ceiling and wall

Tags: walls, ceiling, garage, water-damage

I live in a row/townhouse (in Toronto Canada) with my house being last one. We have balconies instead of backyards. During one of the windstorms, the divider between balconies broke and caused water to seep through. Please take a look at the picture to understand better.

I need advise as where to start (including materials/tools). Does it look like big work, or something a newbie DIYer can also do? I am not looking to make it picture perfect, and even some basic repairs can do for me.

Thanks in advance!

[image: water damage to ceiling and wall]

Comment: Sorry, but this question is too broad. You're asking for an entire strategy based on very little information.

Answer (score 1):

This is correctable with DIY, but depends on the skills you have available. Usually a water damage issue like this will be fixed from the outside in, to keep new storms from spreading more damage. At a high level:

The first step is to fix the exterior. The posts, decking, flashing, and possibly siding on that platform need to be inspected, possibly removed or replaced.

Once that area is dealt with, you can pull drywall in the garage and look at the damage behind it. The longer these leaks have gone on, the more extensive damage you can expect. Cut and remove drywall in straight lines, it will be easier to replace areas that way. And make sure you cut enough to give you room to access whatever space is above the garage to inspect and make repairs.

Repair any damage to the framing first, then the insulation. When all the interior components are looking good, you can replace sheetrock with new sheets of the same thickness. If your previous cuts weren't straight, you should cut straight now so you can butt the new sheetrock against the old in straight lines. Attach with drywall screws, tape the joints, apply joint compound (mud), and sand the area once it's dry (this takes some practice to get it looking right). Don't expect it to look exactly like it did - garage drywall is brownish with whitish streaks where the drywall screws hold it to the studs. The brownish color is weathered and fresh sheetrock will be off-white.

Once the sheetrock is replaced and mudded well you can prime and paint the whole wall and ceiling for a uniform look, or just leave it mismatched if that's OK with you.

Comment: Mud tip, apply a few thin wide coats instead of thick narrow coats.

Comment: Drywall tip: cut out bad sections down the middle of studs so there's room to screw the new pieces in. Also, it's no more difficult to install a 4x4' piece than it is to install a 16x32" piece, so don't be afraid to cut larger sections out to check for damage and make room for repair work.